# intuition behind Vitali's Theorem from Theory of Statistical Hypotheses by Lehmann and Romano

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying prove of Vitali's theorem to myself from Theory of Statistical Hypotheses by Lehmann and Romano:

> Suppose $f_n$ and $f$ are real-valued measurable functions with $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$, except possibly on a set having $\mu$ measure $0$. Assume 
>   $$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n^2(x) d\mu (x) \leq \int f^2(x) d\mu (x) < \infty .$$
>   Then, 
>   $$\int \left | f_n(x) - f(x) \right |^2 d\mu (x) \rightarrow 0$$

I'm wondering what the difference is between proving that $\int \left | f_n(x) - f(x) \right |^2 d\mu (x) \rightarrow 0$ and proving $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$.

I understand that we're not directly finding that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$, but normally if the area under the squared error is $0$ then the functions are equal. What is different when this happens asyptotically?

Or does this theorem actually say that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$? If that is the case then what is the reason for writing it this way? Is there something significant about the notation that indicates something about the result?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to first study types of convergence for measurable functions.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, but you have $\|f_n - f\|_{L^2} \to 0$ so by definiteness of norm $f_n - f \to 0$ almost everywhere.